# How can I prove that A⊕B= A*B+A*B is an associative property?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that A⊕B= A*B+A*B is an associative property or not? A and B are matrices that are both m x m(m by m).

⊕ stands for the addition operation

this is what I did
=A(B)+ A(B)
=2A(B)
so this is not associative is this correct?

I also wanted to if the scalar multiplication property is satisfied and distributive(over the addition operation for matrix)?

Comment: What's an associative property?

Comment: (p + q) + r = p + (q + r)?

Comment: So "has the associative property", not "is an". But then why is $A\oplus B$ simultaneously "the addition operation" applied to $A$ and $B$, and $AB+AB$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(A \oplus B) \oplus C = (2AB)\oplus C = 2ABC+2ABC = 4ABC$
$A \oplus (B \oplus C) = A \oplus (2BC) = 2ABC+2ABC = 4ABC$. 
Thus, the operator is associative

Comment: why do we add C? Thank you!

Comment: That's what the definition is.